# Only the first derived class is being included

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++, and for a school assignment we have to create a base class and create 2 derived classes from it, then display the output of all the associated functions of the two derived classes.

The problem is, when I try to include the two derived classes in my test file, only the one that I include first works. If I reverse the order that I include them, then the one that's now included first works, but the second one doesn't

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Here's my test file:

```
#include "Payment.h"
#include "CashPayment.h" // This one will work
#include "CreditCardPayment.h" // This one won't. Unless you switch them
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Tests the CashPayment and CreditCardPayment classes, derived from the Payment clas
int main() {

   CashPayment firstCash(420);
   cout << "First Cash Payment" << endl 
      << "Amount: " << firstCash.getAmount() << endl
      << firstCash.paymentDetails() << endl;

   CreditCardPayment firstCredit("Mingwu Chen", 123456789, 11, 2016, 100);
   cout << "Number: " << firstCredit.getNumber() << endl
      << "Month: " << firstCredit.getMonth() << endl
      << "Year: " << firstCredit.getYear() << endl
      << "Amount: " << firstCredit.getAmount() << endl
      << firstCredit.paymentDetails() << endl;
}
```

Here's my CashPayment.h file:

```
#ifndef CASHPAYMENT_H
#define CASHPAYMENT_H

#include <string>
#include "Payment.h"
using namespace std;

class CashPayment: public Payment {

   public:

      // Creates a CashPayment with an amount of 0
      CashPayment();

      // Creates a CashPayment with the given amount
      CashPayment(double a);

      // Creates a string out of all the CashPayment details
      string paymentDetails();
};
#endif
```

Here's the CreditCardPayment.h file:

```
#ifndef CASHPAYMENT_H
#define CASHPAYMENT_H

#include <string>
#include "Payment.h"
using namespace std;

class CreditCardPayment: public Payment {

   private:
      string name;
      int cardNumber;
      int expMonth;
      int expYear;

   public:

      // Creates a CreditCardPayment with an amount of 0
      CreditCardPayment();

      // Creates a CreditCardPayment with the given card holder name, card number, expiry month, expiry year, and amount
      CreditCardPayment(string n, int c, int m, int y, double a);

      // Creates a string out of all the CreditCardPayment details
      string paymentDetails();

      // Returns the card holder name
      string getName();

      // Returns the card number
      int getNumber();

      // Returns the expiry month
      int getMonth();

      // Returns the expiry year
      int getYear();

      // Sets the card holder name t0 the given name
      void setName(string n);

      // Sets the card number to the given number
      void setNumber(int c);

      // Sets the expiry month to the given month
      void setMonth(int m);

      // Sets the expiry year to the given year
      void setYear(int y);
};
#endif
```

Here's the Payment.h file:

```
#ifndef PAYMENT_H
#define PAYMENT_H

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Payment {

   private:
      double amount;

   public:
      // Creates a Payment with an amount of 0
      Payment();

      // Creates a Payment with the given amount
      Payment(double a);

      // Returns the amount
      double getAmount();

      // Sets the amount to the given value
      void setAmount(int a);

      // Creates a string out of all the Payment details
      string paymentDetails();
};
#endif
```

I've been up all night trying to figure this out, and I'm offically stumped. Any ideas or suggestions at all with be greatly appreciated.

(PS: Many people on here don't seem to like using namespace std, but that's what my teacher wants)

Comment: _"but that's what my teacher wants"_ Sorry to hear that.

Comment: `using namespace std;`, in a header file, is an excellent way to wreak havoc on a large project where multiple people are working on the same source. It is very unlikely to harm a student project though.

Comment: HINT: Think about what makes a header file unique.

Looks like the copypasta monsta gotcha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both header files have:

```
#ifndef CASHPAYMENT_H
#define CASHPAYMENT_H
```

As such, whichever one is included first, is the one whose contents actually get compiled.

Comment: Holy crap, I can't believe I did that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
#ifndef CASHPAYMENT_H
#define CASHPAYMENT_H

(stuff)

#endif
```

This is called the [include-guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard), and it stops a file being included more than once when the program is compiled.

You shouldn't have `CASHPAYMENT_H` on all three header files - each file needs a **unique** include-guard. It doesn't actually matter what, as long as it's unique in your project, and the header filename in uppercase is a good convention for this.

As an alternative to `#ifndef`, you can use [`#pragma once`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once), which does the same thing:

```
#pragma once

(stuff)
```

(Note there's no `#endif` at the end of the file.)

It's not in the C++ standard but it's supported by pretty much all of the compilers and is a bit clearer.

Comment: Usual `#pragma once` warning. `once`, and all `#pragma`s are implementation specific extensions to C++. They are not part of the standard and may not be supported by all C++ compilers. In fact if a `#pragma` is not supported, the compiler is allowed to silently discard it, leading to comedic hi-jinks. Ensure your compiler supports a pragma before using it. Specific to `once`, there are a few problems that have kept it out of the standard. It is easily confused by a complex build systems that take advantage of mapped drives and symlinks. Use with caution.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply! I can't believe I didn't see that. It's because I copied the CashPayment.h file and then edited it to make the CreditCardPayment.h file. But I must have missed this when I changed it. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

In the CreditCardPayment.h file put this:

```
#ifndef CREDITCARDPAYMENT_H
#define CREDITCARDPAYMENT_H
```

Answer (score -1):

You must copy your code, it is better to build your class from a tool in your IDE.  That will automatically add the header defender for you. And your payment detail function should be **virtual**.

Comment: What IDE do you recommend? My teacher has us using SCITE, and I hate it, so I'm looking for something better.

Comment: QtCreator or VS. If you are using Linux, QtCreator is your best choice.